# Sublime Text 2 Emmet writes undefined after expanding abbrevation

Tags: sublimetext2, undefined, emmet

**Hello experts**

Something weird is happening in Sublime Text 2 after expanding an abbrevation:

```
html>head>title{Kontakt}^body>.row>.small-12.columns>h1{Kontakt}
```

becomes

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
undefined<title>Kontakt</title>
</head>
<body>
undefined<div class="row">
undefinedundefined<div class="small-12 columns">
undefinedundefinedundefined<h1>Kontakt</h1>
undefinedundefined</div>
undefined</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't change any settings so far. I can't figure out why emmet tells me `undefined` instead of writing tabs for indending the code.

Do you have any idea?

Greetings

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed and reinstalled the Emmet package via Package Control. Now it works fine again.